# Largest interval on which the solution exist of ODE $y'=2(1+y)\sqrt{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y$ is the solution of ODE $$y'=2(1+y)\sqrt{y}$$ satisfying $$y(0)=0,y(\pi/2)=1,$$ then the largest interval(to the right of origin) on which the solution exists is

$1.[0,3\pi/4)$

$2.[0,\pi)$

$3.[0,2\pi)$

$4.[0,2\pi/3)$

By variable separable it is difficult to solve. The function $2(1+y)\sqrt{y}$ is not Lipschitz around zero. Then how to find largest interval for solution? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Use the substitution $z^2=y$.

Comment: ok ok ...now i am trying to solve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem looked impossible to me at first. There is the singular solution $y=0$, and if $y\ne0$, then using @frog's hint of $z^2=y$,
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dy}{2(1+y)\sqrt y}&=\int\frac{2z\,dz}{2(1+z^2)z}=\int\frac{dz}{1+z^2}\\&=\tan^{-1}z+C_1=\tan^{-1}\sqrt y+C_1\\
&=\int dx=x+C_2\end{align}$$
So $y=\tan^2(x+C)$ or $y=0$ is the general solution if we don't allow complex solutions. Now at this point, starting from $x=0$, if we choose either solution it doesn't work at $x=\frac{\pi}2$. If $y=0$ then $y\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)=0$ and if $y=\tan^2(x+0)$ then $y\left(x\right)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}2$.

But it turns out that the problem is soluble if we start at the right endpoint. In that case the only solutions possible are $y=\tan^2\left(x-\frac{\pi}4\right)$ and $y=\tan^2\left(x+\frac{\pi}4\right)$. The second solution becomes infinite as $x\rightarrow{\frac{\pi}4}^+$ but the first goes to $0$ at this point, so the solution is
$$y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,&0\le x\le\frac{\pi}4\\\tan^2\left(x-\frac{\pi}4\right),&\frac{\pi}4\le x<\frac{3\pi}4\end{array}\right.$$
And so our solution stops as $x\rightarrow{\frac{3\pi}4}^-$ because then $y\rightarrow\infty$.

A similar example might be something like $y^{\prime}=-\sqrt{1-y^2}$, $y(0)=1$, $y(4)=-1$ with general solution $y=\cos(x-x_0)$ or $y=-1$ or $y=1$. In that case the $y=\cos(x-x_0)$ solution with $x_0\in[0,4-\pi]$ could be inserted between the singular solutions valid near the two endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precise time....